# C# : creating unique one-dimensional arrays from two-dimensional arrays

Tags: c#, arraylist

input Data

```
1 -> [2] 
2 -> [3, 5, 7, 9]
3 -> [4]
4 -> [5]
5 -> [6]
6 -> [7, 9]
7 -> [8]
8 -> [9]
tree child
```

how can i get output like below using data above
a few for loop checks but i couldn't. I want something like combination but infinite

Out data

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

1,2,3,4,5,6,9

1,2,5,6,7,8,9

1,2,5,6,9

1,2,7,8,9

1,2,9
```

Comment: Do you mean that for each possible output, you need it to start with the first element of the very first array (`1`) and end with the last element of the very last array (`9`), and everything in between can be any selection of the (remaining) distinct, ordered elements in all input arrays?

Comment: yes right it should start with 1 and end with 9

Comment: Okay. Is it also correct to assume that each "pair" of consecutive numbers in every out data line need to be present as an array in the input data? E.g. `1,2,7,8,9` is a valid output line because `[1,2], [2,7], [7,8], [8,9]` are all present in your input data, but `1,2,7,9` is _invalid_ because there is no `[7,9]` in your input data?

Comment: 1  -> [2] 2 -> [3, 5, 7, 9]
3 -> [4]
4 -> [5]
5 -> [6]
6 -> [7, 9]
7 -> [8]
8 -> [9]
tree child

Comment: Great, your updated question makes it easier to understand how the number ranges can be put together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This solution works in **.Net 6** and later versions. (It may work in .Net 4.7.2 as well, but not in the provided fiddle.)

---

Assuming your input tree isn't too large, you could use recursion to achieve what you want to do.

Let's say your input data is populated in a `Dictionary`, as follows:

```
var input = new Dictionary<int, int[]>
{
    [1] = new[] { 2 },
    [2] = new[] { 3, 5, 7, 9 },
    [3] = new[] { 4 },
    [4] = new[] { 5 },
    [5] = new[] { 6 },
    [6] = new[] { 7, 9 },
    [7] = new[] { 8 },
    [8] = new[] { 9 }
};

var output = input.GetPossibleRanges();
```

You could then "build" all possible tree branches recursively, using extension methods such as:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<int>> GetPossibleRanges(this Dictionary<int, int[]> dict)
{
    var ranges = new List<int> { dict.Keys.Min() }.BuildRanges(dict);

    return ranges;
}

public static IEnumerable<List<int>> BuildRanges(this List<int> range, Dictionary<int, int[]> dict)
{
    if (dict.TryGetValue(range.Last(), out int[] nextLevel))
    {
        foreach (var child in nextLevel)
        {
            foreach (var grownRange in range.Append(child).ToList().BuildRanges(dict))
            {
                yield return grownRange;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        yield return range;
    }
}
```

---

Given the provided input, the resulting output is then:

```
foreach (var entry in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", entry));
}
```

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,9
1,2,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,5,6,9
1,2,7,8,9
1,2,9
```

---

I've implemented it in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VBe22w).

Comment: Append error. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9 1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9 1,2,3,5,6,7,9 1,2,3,5,7,8,9 1,2,3,5,7,9

Comment: @AtabaySAĞIN That's strange. It works for me (running in Visual Studio 2022 - Enterprise), and also in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VBe22w).

Comment: I am updating. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @AtabaySAĞIN You're welcome! May I ask, do you know what caused the error you were getting?

Comment: .Net 4.6.1 to .Net 4.7.2     It was fixed after updating the library.

Comment: @AtabaySAĞIN Ah, okay, good to know! I will update my answer to inform about that.

Comment: Actually, I can't get it to work in the fiddle when using .Net 4.7.2 as the compiler there. I'll notify about .Net 6 being a working compiler instead.

Answer (score 0):

public static IEnumerable<List> GetPossibleRanges(this Dictionary<int, int[]> dict) {
var ranges = new List { dict.Keys.Min() }.BuildRanges(dict);

```
        return ranges;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<List<int>> BuildRanges(this List<int> range, Dictionary<int, int[]> dict) {
        if (dict.TryGetValue(range.Last(), out int[] nextLevel)) {
            foreach (var child in nextLevel) {
                range.Add(child);

                foreach (var grownRange in range.ToList().BuildRanges(dict)) {
                    yield return grownRange;
                }
            }
        } else {
            yield return range;
        }
    }
```

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9
1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,5,6,7,9
1,2,3,5,7,8,9
1,2,3,5,7,9

range.Append(child).ToList().BuildRanges(dict)

Append Error